# Databases 2nd normal form and foreign keys

Tags: mysql, ms-access, database-design, database-normalization

I am currently working on a database structure in Microsoft Access 2010 and I have come across following question:

I have a table called tblPC and another table called tblOperators:
tblOperators has following attributes: idOperator (Primary key, autoincrement number), idStaff_number(personnel number) and txtOperator_name.

tblPC has following attributes: idPC(Primary key, autoincrement number), txtModelNumber, numPC_serial_number, idOperator(number)

Now I want to connect those two tables: one Operator can operate on one or more PCs, but an PC has only one Operator, which means, that there would be a 1:n-Relation between tblOperators and tblPC.

My question: Is the idOperator Attribut in the PC table correct? I am afraid that it wouldnt match the second normal form because the idOperator has nothing to do with the Primary key?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you don't have composite keys then if you're in 1NF you're automagically in 2NF.

Comment: Unless a column is constrained to have the same value for a column in every row, in which case that column is functionally dependent on {} and can be partially functionally dependent on a one-column candidate key. (Sometimes done in an SQL idiom for type tag columns for declarative enforcement of subtyping. Of course, then the 2NF redundancy isn't problematic.)

Answer (score -1):

It is correct to put the idOperator on the tblPC because you are adding it as a foreign key to represent the singular relationship to the tblOperators. A PC has only one operator.

What does idOperator have to do with the primary key? It represents the single Operator who operates that PC.

Hope that helps.

Comment: No it's not. Explain why you think so.